# invoking HTTP oauth 2.0 from an Azure logic app

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to connect to an Azure web app, and once I have checked that network is correctly configured (I'm able to connect to unsecured resources) I'm stuck with the "Active Directory Oauth" option in the HTTP connector (API web app inside Azure).

[image]

The response is an internal error:

[image]

Are the parameters correctly filled?

And also I have been able to connect with endpoint through Postman Authentication Oauth 2.0. ID Token ins unchecked in App Registration.

[image]

Comment: Try adding /.default at the end of the audience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have created logic app as shown below,
[image]

Get Bearer Token is a http action. Using this request getting bearer token.
[image]
Authentication Type: Basic

User name : Client Id

Password : Client Secret

Added one more Http action with name, Get Data action is using access token from previous step to call api as shown below,
[image]

Able to call api using bearer token and getting data.
[image]

Comment: What's the authorization url? Which format does it have?

Comment: login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token?

Comment: It genetates token but I is not completelly valid: 022-11-13 09:51:50.912 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Exception occurred while processing message.System.UnauthorizedAccessException: IDW10201: Neither scope or roles claim was found in the bearer token.at Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.

Comment: OK, got it. but with "AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL" : true and removing scope requirement from controller. Following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?tabs=aspnetcore