# Deploy Logic App API connections, supply bearer token

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create an application that uses Logic Apps on the back end where my application's users will authenticate to the various connectors Logic Apps uses via my app. I would have the OAuth bearer token at that point. I would then like to deploy Azure API Connections and pass that bearer token in so the user only has to auth once. Is this possible?

Comment: I believe you can either use logic app custom container or API management in azure.

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK, since there isn't a straightforward way to accomplish this**, I believe you'll need to develop your own integration arrangement.

> I am trying to create an application that uses Logic Apps on the back
> end where my application's users will authenticate

I do agree with @ alex using [custom connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/create-logic-apps-connector) may have possibility to connect own application to logic App. But the custom connector creation must satisfy your requirement.

- I am just suggesting that after creation of your own application [create an azure AD application to register your app and to set up authentication](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/logic-apps/logic-apps-custom-api-authentication.md) for calls to custom APIs from Azure Logic Apps.

AAD>> App registrations >> + New Registration
[image]
As shown in above image you can create app registration and select supported account types for Who can use your application or access your API.

- After you have created the application identity, you can configure your Logic App to use it.

> I would then like to deploy Azure API Connections and pass that bearer
> token in so the user only has to auth once. Is this possible?

**Yes, it is possible to deploy Azure API Connections and pass the OAuth bearer token in order to require user authentication only once**. Here [Azure API Management](https://www.solo.io/topics/api-management/azure-api-management/) supports [OAuth 2.0](https://medium.com/@TheCPUTutor/how-to-authenticate-standard-logic-apps-using-oauth-2-0-bearer-token-1f408026f24a) user authorization and Azure Active Directory to secure user access to an API.

- Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74404772/invoking-http-oauth-2-0-from-logicapp-standard/74413314#74413314) link it may helps.